# Maximum call stack size exceeded on form submision

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I red another posts but couldn't realize where is my problem in particular. I think i don't call function more than once on submit. This is a contact form which i want to send via `ajax` to the controller action where the data will be validated and if it is ok will be saved in database table. Can you give me direction where is my mistake? Thank you!
Form:

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="contactProccess()">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <input id="form-token" type="hidden" name="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfParam?>"
                            value="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>" />

                            <div class="col-sm-12 contact-container">

                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h1 class="text-center contact-page-title <?=($message != "" ? " mt0 " : "")?>"><?= $page->title; ?></h1>
                                </div>

                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h60">
                                        <div class="text-input">
                                            <input type="text" name="names" id="fancy-text" />
                                            <label><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Names') ?></label>
                                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h60">
                                        <div class="text-input">
                                            <input type="text" name="email" id="fancy-text"/>
                                            <label>Email</label>
                                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h60">
                                        <div class="text-input">
                                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="fancy-text"/>
                                            <label><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Phone') ?></label>
                                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h60">
                                        <div class="text-input">
                                            <input type="text" name="title" id="fancy-text"/>
                                            <label><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Title') ?></label>
                                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h190">
                                        <div class="text-input">
                                            <textarea class="padding-message" name="message" id="fancy-text"></textarea>
                                            <label><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Message') ?></label>
                                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h100">
                                        <?= '<img src="' . $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src'] . '" alt="CAPTCHA code" height="60" width="120">' ?>
                                        <label><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Security code') ?></label>
                                        <input class="padding-message" name="captcha" id="fancy-text" />
                                        <div class="help-block"></div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="xss-margin"></div><!-- space -->

                                    <div class="contact-form submit-button">
                                        <button type="submit"><?= Yii::t('app','app.Send') ?></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- panel-end -->
                    </form>
```

Ajax:

```
function contactProccess() {
    var name = $('input[name="names"]');
    var email = $('input[name="email"]');
    var phone = $('input[name="phone"]');
    var title = $('input[name="title"]');
    var captcha = $('input[name="captcha"]');
    var message = $('textarea[name="message"]');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/admin/site/contactprocess',
        data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            title: title,
            message: message
        },
        success: function ( data ) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

The action is just a test form now:

```
public function actionContactprocess(){
        var_dump($_POST);die;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply on click event to your submit button to make ajax rather than using obsubmit. Give an id to the button and add click event to it

```
<form>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <input id="form-token" type="hidden" name="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfParam?>"
                            value="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>" />

                            <div class="col-sm-12 contact-container">

                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h1 class="text-center contact-page-title <?=($message != "" ? " mt0 " : "")?>"><?= $page->title; ?></h1>
                                </div>

                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h60">
                                        <div class="text-input">
                                            <input type="text" name="names" id="fancy-text" />
                                            <label><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Names') ?></label>
                                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h60">
                                        <div class="text-input">
                                            <input type="text" name="email" id="fancy-text"/>
                                            <label>Email</label>
                                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h60">
                                        <div class="text-input">
                                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="fancy-text"/>
                                            <label><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Phone') ?></label>
                                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h60">
                                        <div class="text-input">
                                            <input type="text" name="title" id="fancy-text"/>
                                            <label><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Title') ?></label>
                                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h190">
                                        <div class="text-input">
                                            <textarea class="padding-message" name="message" id="fancy-text"></textarea>
                                            <label><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Message') ?></label>
                                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="contact-form lg-margin h100">
                                        <?= '<img src="' . $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src'] . '" alt="CAPTCHA code" height="60" width="120">' ?>
                                        <label><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Security code') ?></label>
                                        <input class="padding-message" name="captcha" id="fancy-text" />
                                        <div class="help-block"></div>
                                    </div><!-- End .form-group -->

                                    <div class="xss-margin"></div><!-- space -->

                                    <div class="contact-form submit-button">
                                        <button id="submit-btn"><?= Yii::t('app','app.Send') ?></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- panel-end -->
                    </form>
```

Here's the js method for the same:-

```
$('#submit-btn').click(function(){
    var name = $('input[name="names"]');
    var email = $('input[name="email"]');
    var phone = $('input[name="phone"]');
    var title = $('input[name="title"]');
    var captcha = $('input[name="captcha"]');
    var message = $('textarea[name="message"]');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/admin/site/contactprocess',
        data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            title: title,
            message: message
        },
        success: function ( data ) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Nothing change. Again maximum call stack.

Comment: Saw the problem. I was giving the whole input object and not it's value.